# ASP.Net Core Web Application Unable to Create SSL Connection With API When Both Are Run In Docker

Tags: docker, api, asp.net-core, ssl, https

I have an ASP.Net web application and a separate ASP.Net API that I have created using .Net 5 that both need to be run in Docker, but as separate applications. Both Docker images run fine on their own, and I can hit the API while it's running in Docker with Postman without any issues. The problem comes when I try to send a request to the API in the web application using an HttpClient with this code:

```
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private async Task<ApplicationUser> LdapRest(string apiUrl, LoginPostModel postObject)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = null;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, postObject, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((Task<string> x) =>
                {
                    if (x.IsFaulted) throw x.Exception;
                    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationUser>(x.Result);
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "LdapRest Failed");
        }
        return user;
    }
```

I get the error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
```

I believe this stems from using the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` middleware, which is required for this application. I'm using a self-signed cert using the `dotnet dev-certs https` command and referencing it in both containers with environment variables for Kestrel. I tried using the method outlined [here](https://medium.com/it-dead-inside/docker-containers-and-localhost-cannot-assign-requested-address-6ac7bc0d042b), where you create a bridge network in Docker and having both images on it and passing in the URI for the API as an environment variable using the API's container name, but it hasn't worked for me, and I'm struggling to find any other workable solutions to fix this issue that aren't "don't use https redirection".

Comment: this `The problem comes when I try to do an action in the web application that tries to make a call to the API` requires more explanation. As I understand that means you perform some action with `HttpClient` (or something like that) to send a http request to some API which is not clearly described as your own API (in that same app) or some third-party API (in some other process or server)?  I don't think `https redirection` is involved here, it just tries to redirect the request from `http` to `https`. Once your api supports `https`, https redirection is just OK.

Comment: @KingKing, I've updated the question to hopefully clarify what's going on. Also, from what I've read, the https redirection in Kestrel requires that there's a valid certificate, though I may be understanding that wrong.

Comment: what is this `apiUrl`? if it points to some external server, the exception then is thrown as a response from that server (not your api). That means that server api does not support https.

Comment: Both the web application and the API are being run locally on my computer. I am able to run them both using Kestrel from Visual Studio, and it works. I can also run the API inside Docker and the web application from Visual Studio and it works. I am using https://localhost:5555/api as the location to the API in both of those scenarios. It's just the scenario where they're both in Docker containers where there is an issue. Both containers have both an http and https port exposed, so it should be supported.

Comment: I think you can try using some other tool (e.g: Postman) to post a simple request to `apiUrl` and check out the result (to see if it actually works by returning a response). That's kind of unit testing, if that does not even work, you can just focus on fixing the issue on one end (the api) and let the other end (the web) aside.

Comment: Postman can hit the API without any issues at both the http and https URLs.

Comment: I can understand the exception, for 2 reasons: first for the error `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` - this is because the domain name info in the self-signed cert is not matched with the server host name. You can recreate your self-signed cert to fix that error. The second for the error `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` - this is due to using the self-signed cert. So it's hard to fix. If for the debugging/development purpose only, you can find a way to disable that `certificate validation`.